# Java calling function or using object from Main class in sub class

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point

I need help with some Java code. I have Main class where all the objects from GUI are defined in so I created a function for appending text to a TextArea in Main class and now I need to call the function from a Sub class to append text to the text area.

Main class:

```
public static String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");    
ConsoleDebug debug = new ConsoleDebug();

    public void writeTextArea(String string) {
        jTextArea2.append(string);
    }
```

Sub class:

```
package AppPackage;

import static AppPackage.MainGUI.newline;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Calendar;

//Debuging console
public class ConsoleDebug {
    public java.sql.Timestamp currentTimestamp() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
        return timestamp;
    }

    //Message
    public void message(String newText) {
        logWrite("",newText);
    }

    //Info message
    public void info(String newText) {
        logWrite("|INFO| ",newText);
    }

    //Error message
    public void error(String newText) {
        logWrite("|ERROR| ",newText);
    }

    //Critical message
    public void critical(String newText) {
        logWrite("|CRITICAL| ",newText);
    }

    //Write to log
    private void logWrite(String prefix, String newText) {
        writeTextArea("[" + currentTimestamp() + "] " + prefix + newText + newline);

        File launcherLog = new File("launcher.log");
        if(!launcherLog.exists() || launcherLog.isDirectory()) {
            // Stream to write file
            FileOutputStream fout;      
            try
            {
                // Open an output stream
                fout = new FileOutputStream("launcher.log");

                // Print a line of text
                PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(fout);
                stream.println("[" + currentTimestamp() + "] " + prefix + newText);

        // Close our output stream
        fout.close();       
            }
            // Catches any error conditions
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.err.println("Unable to create log file");
            }
        }
        else {
            try {
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("launcher.log", true)));
                out.println("[" + currentTimestamp() + "] " + prefix  + newText);
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
                System.err.println("Unable to edit log file");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks okay I think, but the error

```
"Can't find symbol writeTextArea(String)"
```

shows up when I try to

```
writeTextArea("[" + currentTimestamp() + "] " + prefix + newText + newline);
```

from my private logWrite(String, String) function. Any ideas why it does that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that `ConsoleDebug` is a subclass. Maybe you need to declare as such:

```
public class ConsoleDebug extends MainClass{
```

This way you can call `writeTextArea` from `ConsoleDebug` as it is a real subclass of main class.

Comment: I've already tried extends MainClass but that gives me another error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
 at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Win32GraphicsConfig.java:222)
 at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:505)
 at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
 at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:181)
 at AppPackage.MainGUI.<init>(MainGUI.java:29)
 at AppPackage.ConsoleDebug.<init>(ConsoleDebug.java:24)
......

Comment: Instead of `MainClass' you must use the name of your main class (which I don't know).

Comment: It is backlogging on MainGUI.java:24 and ConsoleDebug.java:24) which are ConsoleDebug debug = new ConsoleDebug(); and public class ConsoleDebug extends MainGUI {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70027/discussion-between-sonic656-and-paco-abato).

Comment: When you create a new ConsoleDebug you are also creating a main class object (because it's the parent class), which is creating a new ConsoleDebug, etc. You can pass the ConsoleDebug object as constructor parameter instead of creating it. Or use a setter method.

Answer (score 1):

If extends keyword gives an error then Write your

```
public void writeTextArea(String string)
```

method as

```
public static void writeTextArea(String string) 
{
    jTextArea2.append(string);
}
```

and simply access the method as class_name.method name i.e.

```
Main.writeTextArea("[" + currentTimestamp() + "] " + prefix + newText + newline);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ConsoleDebug`  is subclass for `MainClass` class, than you need to use extend keyword.

Inside of your ConsoleDebug  definition write this:

```
public class ConsoleDebug extends MainClass { 
 ...
}
```

Than all public/protected methods from `MainClass` can be used inside `ConsoleDebug` class.

Comment: But then I can't add SubClass debug = new SubClass(); to main class and call SubClass's functions, and that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this job, a simple one is that you can define the method writeTextArea static. In order to do this, you need to define jTextArea2 as static too, and init it before you new ConsoleDebug. Since you are not giving the complete Main, I can only give you a draft:

```
public class Main {
    static JTextArea jTextArea2;

    public static void main() {
        jTextArea2 = ...;
        ConsoleDebug debug = new ConsoleDebug();
        ....
    }

    public static void writeTextArea(String string) {
        jTextArea2.append(string);
    }
}
```

Then you can change the writeTextArea into Main.writeTextArea in your subclass, you will get things done.